# How can I create a beautiful symbol table?

Tags: tables, symbols, positioning, indexing

One part of my "Geometrie und Topologie" book is a symbol table that allows students to quickly find the right words when they don't understand a symbol. This makes searching via the index / Wikipedia / Google / math.SE much easier. But currently it doesn't look very nice.

The complete sources of the document are [here](https://github.com/MartinThoma/LaTeX-examples/tree/master/documents/GeoTopo).

### Working Example

The following example example compiles almost (except for references and page numbers) to the symbol table I currently have:

```
\documentclass[DIV15,BCOR12mm]{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{paper=a5,twoside=true}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}% math symbols / fonts
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % this is needed for correct output of umlauts in pdf
\usepackage[bookmarks,bookmarksnumbered,hypertexnames=false,pdfpagelayout=OneColumn,colorlinks,hyperindex=false]{hyperref} % has to be after makeidx
\hypersetup{hidelinks=true}
\usepackage{braket}         % needed for \Set
\usepackage{parskip}        % nicer paragraphs
\usepackage[german,nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref} % has to be after hyperref, ntheorem, amsthm

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]%
{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\thechapter.\ #1}}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]%
{\markright{\MakeUppercase{\thesection.\ #1}}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\newcommand{\helv}{%
\fontfamily{phv}\fontseries{b}\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\helv \thepage}
\fancyhead[LE]{\helv \leftmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\helv \rightmark}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\allowdisplaybreaks
\usepackage{microtype}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% shortcuts                                                         %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\def\fB{\mathfrak{B}}
\def\calS{\mathcal{S}}
\def\fT{\mathfrak{T}}
\def\fU{\mathfrak{U}}
\def\atlas{\ensuremath{\mathcal{A}}}
\def\praum{\ensuremath{\mathcal{P}}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\rang}{Rg}

\newcommand\dcup{\mathbin{\dot{\cup}}}
\def\GL{\ensuremath{\mathrm{GL}}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Homoo}{\textnormal{Homöo}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Iso}{Iso}
\def\SL{\ensuremath{\mathrm{SL}}}
\def\PSL{\ensuremath{\mathrm{PSL}}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Perm}{Perm}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Sym}{Sym}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Fix}{Fix}
\newcommand{\ts}[1]{\textnormal{#1}} % textual subscript
\newcommand{\kappanor}{\kappa_{\ts{Nor}}}

\def\mda{\ensuremath{\mathbb{A}}}
\def\mdp{\ensuremath{\mathbb{P}}}
\def\mdc{\ensuremath{\mathbb{C}}}
\def\mdk{\ensuremath{\mathbb{K}}}
\def\mdr{\ensuremath{\mathbb{R}}}
\def\mdq{\ensuremath{\mathbb{Q}}}
\def\mdz{\ensuremath{\mathbb{Z}}}
\def\mdn{\ensuremath{\mathbb{N}}}
\def\mdh{\ensuremath{\mathbb{H}}}

\begin{document}
\appendix
\markboth{Symbolverzeichnis}{Symbolverzeichnis}
\twocolumn
\chapter*{Symbolverzeichnis}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Symbolverzeichnis}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Mengenoperationen                                                 %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section*{Mengenoperationen}
$A^C\;\;\;$ Komplement der Menge $A$\\
$\mathcal{P}(M)\;\;\;$ Potenzmenge von $M$\\
$\overline{M}\;\;\;$ Abschluss der Menge $M$\\
$\partial M\;\;\;$ Rand der Menge $M$\\
$M^\circ\;\;\;$ Inneres der Menge $M$\\
$A \times B\;\;\;$ Kreuzprodukt zweier Mengen\\
$A \subseteq B\;\;\;$ Teilmengenbeziehung\\
$A \subsetneq B\;\;\;$ echte Teilmengenbeziehung\\
$A \setminus B\;\;\;$ $A$ ohne $B$\\
$A \cup B\;\;\;$ Vereinigung\\
$A \dcup B\;\;\;$ Disjunkte Vereinigung\\
$A \cap B\;\;\;$ Schnitt\\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Geometrie                                                         %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section*{Geometrie}
$AB\;\;\;$ Gerade durch die Punkte $A$ und $B$\\
$\overline{AB}\;\;\;$ Strecke mit Endpunkten $A$ und $B$\\
$\triangle ABC\;\;\;$ Dreieck mit Eckpunkten $A, B, C$\\
$\overline{AB} \cong \overline{CD}\;\;\;$ Die Strecken $\overline{AB}$ und $\overline{CD}$ sind isometrisch\\
$|K|\;\;\;$ Geometrische Realisierung des Simplizialkomplexes $K$\\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Gruppen                                                           %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section*{Gruppen}
$\Homoo(X)\;\;\;$ Homöomorphismengruppe\\
$\Iso(X)\;\;\;$ Isometriengruppe\\
$\GL_n(K)\;\;\;$ Allgemeine lineare Gruppe\footnote{von \textit{\textbf{G}eneral \textbf{L}inear Group}}\\
$\SL_n(K)\;\;\;$ Spezielle lineare Gruppe\\
$\PSL_n(K)\;\;\;$ Projektive lineare Gruppe\\
$\Perm(X)\;\;\;$ Permutationsgruppe\\
$\Sym(X)\;\;\;$ Symmetrische Gruppe
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Wege                                                              %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section*{Wege}
$\gamma: I \rightarrow X\;\;\;$ Ein Weg\\
$[\gamma]\;\;\;$ Homotopieklasse von $\gamma$\\
$\gamma_1 * \gamma_2\;\;\;$ Zusammenhängen von Wegen\\
$\gamma_1 \sim \gamma_2\;\;\;$ Homotopie von Wegen\\
$\overline{\gamma}(x) = \gamma(1-x)\;\;\;$ Inverser Weg\\
$C := \gamma([0,1])\;\;\;$ Bild eines Weges $\gamma$

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Weiteres                                                          %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section*{Weiteres}
$\fB\;\;\;$ Basis einer Topologie\\
$\calS\;\;\;$ Subbasis einer Topologie\\
$\fB_\delta(x)\;\;\;$ $\delta$-Kugel um $x$\\
$\fT\;\;\;$ Topologie\\

$\atlas\;\;\;$ Atlas\\
$\praum\;\;\;$ Projektiver Raum\\
$\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle\;\;\;$ Skalarprodukt\\
$X /_\sim\;\;\;$ $X$ modulo $\sim$\\
$[x]_\sim\;\;\;$ Äquivalenzklassen von $x$ bzgl. $\sim$\\
$\| x \|\;\;\;$ Norm von $x$\\
$| x |\;\;\;$ Betrag von $x$\\
$\langle a \rangle\;\;\;$ Erzeugnis von $a$\\

$S^n\;\;\;$ Sphäre\\
$T^n\;\;\;$ Torus\\

$f \circ g\;\;\;$ Verkettung von $f$ und $g$\\
$\pi_X\;\;\;$ Projektion auf $X$\\
$f|_U\;\;\;$ $f$ eingeschränkt auf $U$\\
$f^{-1}(M)\;\;\;$ Urbild von $M$\\
$\rang(M)\;\;\;$ Rang von $M$\\
$\chi(K)\;\;\;$ Euler-Charakteristik von $K$\\
$\Delta^k\;\;\;$ Standard-Simplex\\
$X \# Y\;\;\;$ Verklebung von $X$ und $Y$\\
$d_n\;\;\;$ Lineare Abbildung aus \cref{kor:9.11}\\
$A \cong B\;\;\;$ $A$ ist isometrisch zu $B$\\
$f_*\;\;\;$ Abbildung zwischen Fundamentalgruppen (vgl. \cpageref{korr:11.5})
\onecolumn

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Zahlenmengen                                                      %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section*{Zahlenmengen}
$\mdn = \Set{1, 2, 3, \dots} \;\;\;$ Natürliche Zahlen\\
$\mdz = \mdn \cup \Set{0, -1, -2, \dots} \;\;\;$ Ganze Zahlen\\
$\mdq = \mdz \cup \Set{\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}} = \Set{\frac{z}{n} \text{ mit } z \in \mdz \text{ und } n \in \mdz \setminus \Set{0}} \;\;\;$ Rationale Zahlen\\
$\mdr = \mdq \cup \Set{\sqrt{2}, -\sqrt[3]{3}, \dots}\;\;\;$ Reele Zahlen\\
$\mdr_+\;$ Echt positive reele Zahlen\\
$\mdr_{+,0}^n := \Set{(x_1, \dots, x_n) \in \mdr^n | x_n \geq 0}\;\;\;$ Halbraum\\
$\mdr^\times = \mdr \setminus \Set{0} \;$ Einheitengruppe von $\mdr$\\
$\mdc = \Set{a+ib|a,b \in \mdr}\;\;\;$ Komplexe Zahlen\\
$\mdp = \Set{2, 3, 5, 7, \dots}\;\;\;$ Primzahlen\\
$\mdh = \Set{z \in \mdc | \Im{z} > 0}\;\;\;$ obere Halbebene\\
$I = [0,1] \subsetneq \mdr\;\;\;$ Einheitsintervall\\

$f:S^1 \hookrightarrow \mdr^2\;\;\;$ Einbettung der Kreislinie in die Ebene\\
$\pi_1(X,x)\;\;\;$ Fundamentalgruppe im topologischen Raum $X$ um $x \in X$\\
$\Fix(f)\;\;\;$ Menge der Fixpunkte der Abbildung $f$\\
$\|\cdot\|_2\;\;\;$ 2-Norm; Euklidische Norm\\
$\kappa\;\;\;$ Krümmung\\
$\kappa_{\ts{Nor}}\;\;\;$ Normalenkrümmung\\
$V(f)\;\;\;$ Nullstellenmenge von $f$\footnote{von \textit{\textbf{V}anishing Set}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Krümmung                                                          %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section*{Krümmung}
$D_p F: \mdr^2 \rightarrow \mdr^3\;\;\;$ Lineare Abbildung mit Jacobi-Matrix in $p$ (siehe \cpageref{def:Tangentialebene})\\
$T_s S\;\;\;$ Tangentialebene an $S \subseteq \mdr^3$ durch $s \in S$\\
$d_s n(x)\;\;\;$ Weingarten-Abbildung\\
\end{document}
```

### Rendered

[image]

[image]

### Question

I would like to know how to make this symbol table "nicer".

One way I could imagine how to improve it, would be by aligning the content on the first page below the section "Gruppen". But I don't want to restrict answers to this.

### What I've tried

#### tabular

I've tried to use the `tabular` environment:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Mengenoperationen                                                 %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section*{Mengenoperationen}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
    $A^C$           & Komplement der Menge $A$\\
    $\mathcal{P}(M)$& Potenzmenge von $M$\\
    $\overline{M}$  & Abschluss der Menge $M$\\
    $\partial M$    & Rand der Menge $M$\\
    $M^\circ$       & Inneres der Menge $M$\\
    $A \times B$    & Kreuzprodukt zweier Mengen\\
    $A \subseteq B$ & Teilmengenbeziehung\\
    $A \subsetneq B$& echte Teilmengenbeziehung\\
    $A \setminus B$ & $A$ ohne $B$\\
    $A \cup B$      & Vereinigung\\
    $A \dcup B$     & Disjunkte Vereinigung\\
    $A \cap B$      & Schnitt
\end{tabular}
```

but then I get this:

[image]

#### itemize

```
\section*{Mengenoperationen}\leavevmode
\begin{itemize}
    \itemsep0em 
    \item[$A^C$]            Komplement der Menge $A$\\
    \item[$\mathcal{P}(M)$] Potenzmenge von $M$\\
    \item[$\overline{M}$]   Abschluss der Menge $M$\\
    \item[$\partial M$]     Rand der Menge $M$\\
    \item[$M^\circ$]        Inneres der Menge $M$\\
    \item[$A \times B$]     Kreuzprodukt zweier Mengen\\
    \item[$A \subseteq B$]  Teilmengenbeziehung\\
    \item[$A \subsetneq B$] echte Teilmengenbeziehung\\
    \item[$A \setminus B$]  $A$ ohne $B$\\
    \item[$A \cup B$]       Vereinigung\\
    \item[$A \dcup B$]      Disjunkte Vereinigung\\
    \item[$A \cap B$]       Schnitt
\end{itemize}
```

results in much too high spacing:

[image]

Comment: What about actually using a `tabular` environment for the purpose of alignment? I used the `nomencl` package for my thesis, it turned out quite nice: http://tinyurl.com/oqny954

Comment: an obvious approach is to align the symbols and their meanings in two (tabbed) columns, as often done in an index of notation in a textbook.  that would avoid "mixing" of meaning info in with the symbols in the left-hand column.  i'd also suggest setting the meaning column ragged right, to avoid uneven spacing, which makes the output hard to read and which i find especially annoying in an already "spacy" context like this.

Comment: @Holene I've tried `tabular`, but somehow this seems not to work with two columns (see above). Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @moose: How about some kind of an index or a glossary, there are certainly packages, that could handle such a feature, e.g. "Symbol A   some description", where "some description" replaces the page reference, perhaps as a link, jumping to some definition of the symbol? The advantage of 'index' or 'glossary' packages is, that they already have a two (or even more) columned layout.

Comment: @ChristianH. I have tried that. If I remember it correctly, I've switched to this more manual solution, because some texts are quite long (see last two sections). So I can't only have a double column style. But on the other hand, for most of the content a double column design works quite well.

Comment: if you'd like to stick with a manual solution, you could use a list, something like: `\begin{itemize}\item[$A\cup B$] union of two sets....\end{itemize}`. This keeps the alignment idea alive, and allows page breaks; if you go down the route of `glossaries`, the documentation is great, together with [http://www.latex-community.org/know-how/latex/55-latex-general/263-glossaries-nomenclature-lists-of-symbols-and-acronyms](http://www.latex-community.org/know-how/latex/55-latex-general/263-glossaries-nomenclature-lists-of-symbols-and-acronyms)

Comment: @cmhughes I don't know how to reduce the spacing with itemize (see amendment above)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use the `xtab` package and its environment `xtabular`. It functions very much like the `longtable` environment does, in that it can break across columns and pages; however, it's also compatible with twocolumn mode, whereas `longtable` is not.

I suggest you adjust the column width of the first table column (the symbol column) so that it's just wide enough to contain the widest symbolic entry within each section. Then, adjust the second column so that the entire table is as wide as `\columnwidth`. Given the narrow measure of the second column within a table, "full" justification isn't advisable. Instead, use `\RaggedRight` (provided by the package `ragged2e`), which allows hyphenation. (In contrast, `\raggedright` does not allow hyphenation.)

The example shows only the first page of your larger example.

[image]

```
\documentclass[DIV15,BCOR12mm]{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{paper=a5,twoside=true}

\usepackage{array,xtab,ragged2e}
\newlength\mylengtha
\newlength\mylengthb
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}p{#1}}
\tabcolsep=3pt % default: 6pt

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}% math symbols / fonts
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % this is needed for correct 
                            % output of umlauts in pdf
\usepackage{braket}         % needed for \Set
\usepackage{parskip}        % nicer paragraphs

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]%
{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\thechapter.\ #1}}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]%
{\markright{\MakeUppercase{\thesection.\ #1}}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\newcommand{\helv}{%
\fontfamily{phv}\fontseries{b}\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\helv \thepage}
\fancyhead[LE]{\helv \leftmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\helv \rightmark}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\allowdisplaybreaks
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{hyperref} % has to be after makeidx
\hypersetup{bookmarks,bookmarksnumbered,hypertexnames=false,
   pdfpagelayout=OneColumn,colorlinks,hyperindex=false,
   hidelinks=true}
\usepackage[german,nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref} 
   % has to be after hyperref, ntheorem, amsthm

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% shortcuts                                                         %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\def\fB{\mathfrak{B}}
\def\calS{\mathcal{S}}
\def\fT{\mathfrak{T}}
\def\fU{\mathfrak{U}}
\def\atlas{\ensuremath{\mathcal{A}}}
\def\praum{\ensuremath{\mathcal{P}}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\rang}{Rg}

\newcommand\dcup{\mathbin{\dot{\cup}}}
\def\GL{\ensuremath{\mathrm{GL}}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Homoo}{\textnormal{Homöo}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Iso}{Iso}
\def\SL{\ensuremath{\mathrm{SL}}}
\def\PSL{\ensuremath{\mathrm{PSL}}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Perm}{Perm}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Sym}{Sym}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Fix}{Fix}
\newcommand{\ts}[1]{\textnormal{#1}} % textual subscript
\newcommand{\kappanor}{\kappa_{\ts{Nor}}}

\def\mda{\ensuremath{\mathbb{A}}}
\def\mdp{\ensuremath{\mathbb{P}}}
\def\mdc{\ensuremath{\mathbb{C}}}
\def\mdk{\ensuremath{\mathbb{K}}}
\def\mdr{\ensuremath{\mathbb{R}}}
\def\mdq{\ensuremath{\mathbb{Q}}}
\def\mdz{\ensuremath{\mathbb{Z}}}
\def\mdn{\ensuremath{\mathbb{N}}}
\def\mdh{\ensuremath{\mathbb{H}}}

\begin{document}
\appendix
\markboth{Symbolverzeichnis}{Symbolverzeichnis}

\twocolumn
\chapter*{Symbolverzeichnis}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Symbolverzeichnis}

%%%%% Mengenoperationen                                                 
\section*{Mengenoperationen}

% Set \mylengtha to widest element in first column; adjust
% \mylengthb so that the width of the table is \columnwidth
\settowidth\mylengtha{$A \subseteq B$}
\setlength\mylengthb{\dimexpr\columnwidth-\mylengtha-2\tabcolsep\relax}

\begin{xtabular}{@{} p{\mylengtha} P{\mylengthb} @{}}
$A^C $           & Komplement der Menge $A$\\
$\mathcal{P}(M)$ & Potenzmenge von $M$\\
$\overline{M}$   & Abschluss der Menge $M$\\
$\partial M$     & Rand der Menge $M$\\
$M^\circ$        & Inneres der Menge $M$\\
$A \times B$     & Kreuzprodukt zweier Mengen\\
$A \subseteq B$  & Teilmengenbeziehung\\
$A \subsetneq B$ & echte Teilmengenbeziehung\\
$A \setminus B$  & $A$ ohne $B$\\
$A \cup B$       & Vereinigung\\
$A \dcup B$      & Disjunkte Vereinigung\\
$A \cap B$       & Schnitt
\end{xtabular}

%%%%% Geometrie                                                         
\section*{Geometrie}

\settowidth\mylengtha{$\overline{AB} \cong \overline{CD}$}
\setlength\mylengthb{\dimexpr\columnwidth-\mylengtha-2\tabcolsep\relax}

\begin{xtabular}{@{} p{\mylengtha} P{\mylengthb} @{}}
$AB$ & Gerade durch die Punkte $A$ und $B$\\
$\overline{AB}$ & Strecke mit Endpunkten $A$ und $B$\\
$\triangle ABC$ & Dreieck mit Eckpunkten $A, B, C$\\
$\overline{AB} \cong \overline{CD}$ & Die Strecken $\overline{AB}$ und $\overline{CD}$ sind isometrisch\\
$|K|$ & Geometrische Realisierung des Simplizialkomplexes~$K$
\end{xtabular}

%%%%% Gruppen                                                           
\section*{Gruppen}

\settowidth\mylengtha{$\Homoo(X)$}
\setlength\mylengthb{\dimexpr\columnwidth-\mylengtha-2\tabcolsep\relax}

\begin{xtabular}{@{} p{\mylengtha} P{\mylengthb} @{}}
$\Homoo(X)$ & Homöomorphis\-men\-gruppe\\
$\Iso(X)$   & Isometriengruppe\\
$\GL_n(K)$  & Allgemeine lineare Gruppe (von \textit{\textbf{G}eneral \textbf{L}inear Group})\\
$\SL_n(K)$  & Spezielle lineare Gruppe\\
$\PSL_n(K)$ & Projektive lineare Gruppe\\
$\Perm(X)$  & Permutationsgruppe\\
$\Sym(X)$   & Symmetrische Gruppe
\end{xtabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I change the font-size, for example if I want to use `/scriptsize`?

Comment: @alper - I assume you're referring to the fontsize of the tabular material, not the sectioning headers. If this assumption is correct, I'd insert `\scriptsize` immediately after each of the three `\section*` directives. Then, be sure to recompile twice.

Answer (score 3):

Late to the party, but here's a modification of [another answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/653479/4427).

```
\documentclass[DIV15,BCOR12mm]{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{paper=a5,twoside=true}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}% math symbols / fonts
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % this is needed for correct output of umlauts in pdf
\usepackage{braket}         % needed for \Set
\usepackage{parskip}        % nicer paragraphs
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage[
  bookmarks,
  bookmarksnumbered,
  hypertexnames=false,
  pdfpagelayout=OneColumn,
  colorlinks,
  hyperindex=false,
  hidelinks=true,
]{hyperref} % has to be last (almost)
\usepackage[german,nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref} % has to be after hyperref, ntheorem, amsthm

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\thechapter.\ #1}}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\MakeUppercase{\thesection.\ #1}}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\newcommand{\helv}{\fontfamily{phv}\fontseries{b}\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\helv \thepage}
\fancyhead[LE]{\helv \leftmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\helv \rightmark}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhead{}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
}

\allowdisplaybreaks

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% shortcuts                                                         %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\fB{\mathfrak{B}}
\newcommand\calS{\mathcal{S}}
\newcommand\fT{\mathfrak{T}}
\newcommand\fU{\mathfrak{U}}
\newcommand\atlas{\mathcal{A}}
\newcommand\praum{\mathcal{P}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\rang}{Rg}

\newcommand\dcup{\mathbin{\dot{\cup}}}
\DeclareMathOperator\GL{\mathrm{GL}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Homoo}{\textnormal{Homöo}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Iso}{Iso}
\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}
\DeclareMathOperator\PSL{PSL}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Perm}{Perm}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Sym}{Sym}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Fix}{Fix}
\newcommand{\ts}[1]{\textnormal{#1}} % textual subscript
\newcommand{\kappanor}{\kappa_{\ts{Nor}}}

\newcommand\mda{\mathbb{A}}
\newcommand\mdp{\mathbb{P}}
\newcommand\mdc{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand\mdk{\mathbb{K}}
\newcommand\mdr{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand\mdq{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand\mdz{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand\mdn{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand\mdh{\mathbb{H}}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\symbolswd}
\newenvironment{symbols}
 {%
  \begin{multicols*}{2}[\chapter*{Symbolverzeichnis}]
  \small
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
  \edef\current@symbolswd{\the\symbolswd}%
  \interlinepenalty=10000 % no page break in a two line entry
}
 {%
  \ifdim\current@symbolswd=\symbolswd
  \else
    \@latex@warning@no@line{Rerun to get list of symbols right}%
  \fi
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\global\symbolswd=\the\symbolswd}%
  \end{multicols*}
}
\newcommand{\entry}[2]{%
  \par
  \sbox\z@{$#1$\qquad}%
  \ifdim\wd\z@>\symbolswd \setlength{\symbolswd}{\wd\z@}\fi
  \raggedright
  \hangindent=\symbolswd
  \makebox[\symbolswd][s]{$#1$\leaders\hbox to 4pt{\hss.\hss}\hfill}%
  \hspace{0pt}#2\par
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{symbols}

\section*{Mengenoperationen}

\entry{A^C}{Komplement der Menge~$A$}
\entry{\mathcal{P}(M)}{Potenzmenge von~$M$}
\entry{\overline{M}}{Abschluss der Menge~$M$}
\entry{\partial M}{Rand der Menge~$M$}
\entry{M^\circ}{Inneres der Menge~$M$}
\entry{A \times B}{Kreuzprodukt zweier Mengen}
\entry{A \subseteq B}{Teilmengenbeziehung}
\entry{A \subsetneq B}{echte Teilmengenbeziehung}
\entry{A \setminus B}{$A$ ohne~$B$}
\entry{A \cup B}{Vereinigung}
\entry{A \dcup B}{Disjunkte Vereinigung}
\entry{A \cap B}{Schnitt}

\section*{Geometrie}

\entry{AB}{Gerade durch die Punkte $A$ und~$B$}
\entry{\overline{AB}}{Strecke mit Endpunkten $A$ und~$B$}
\entry{\triangle ABC}{Dreieck mit Eckpunkten $A, B, C$}
\entry{\overline{AB} \cong \overline{CD}}{Die Strecken $\overline{AB}$
   und $\overline{CD}$ sind isometrisch}
\entry{|K|}{Geometrische Realisierung des Simplizialkomplexes~$K$}

\section*{Gruppen}

\entry{\Homoo(X)}{Homöomorphis\-men\-gruppe}
\entry{\Iso(X)}{Isometriengruppe}
\entry{\GL_n(K)}{Allgemeine lineare Gruppe
  (von \textit{\textbf{G}eneral \textbf{L}inear Group})}
\entry{\SL_n(K)}{Spezielle lineare Gruppe}
\entry{\PSL_n(K)}{Projektive lineare Gruppe}
\entry{\Perm(X)}{Permutationsgruppe}
\entry{\Sym(X)}{Symmetrische Gruppe}
\end{symbols}

\end{document}
```

The advantage is that this code doesn't use `tabular` (or variation thereof).

Notable differences: `\parskip` is set to zero; `multicols` is used to get two columns, so page breaks are automatic; `\small` and `\raggedright` are needed because of narrow columns.

[image]