# Align with dots instead of empty space

Tags: align

I have in my report a list of definitions which I now pretty aligned so that the definitions (on the right) align nicely. Now I decided that I might want to add dots in between (similar to the table of contents) while preserving the alignment. I have read things about tables and using \dotfill, but I cannot manage to keep the alignment. Also since some definitions go over two lines.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{bm,bbm}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    &\textit{a}&& \text{Allele}\\
    &\textit{m} \in \{1,..., M\}&& \text{Marker}\\
    &\textit{k} \in \{1,..., K\}&& \text{Contributor}\\
    &g_{m,k} = (g_{m,k,1},g_{m,k,2})&& \text{Genotype of contributor $k$ at marker $m$, consisting of two alleles}\\
    &\textbf{g}_{m} = (g_{m,1},...,g_{m,K})&& \text{Set of genotypes for all $K$ contributors}\\
    &\textbf{A}_m && \text{All alleles at marker $m$ observed in database plus new alleles discovered}\\
    &&&\text{when individuals are added}\\
    &\textbf{Y}_m && \text{Observed peak heights of the alleles in \textbf{A}}_m\\
    & Y_{m,a} && \text{Observed peak height of allele $a$ at marker $m$}\\
    & Y_{m,a,k} && \text{Peak height contribution of contributor $k$ to $Y_{m,a}$}\\
    & \mathbb{Q}_m = \{(a,b): a,b\in \textbf{A}_m\} && \text{The set of all possible genotypes at marker $m$}\\
    &\pi_k && \text{Mixture proportion: proportion of total DNA added by contributor $k$}\\
    &\bm{\pi} = (\pi_1, ..., \pi_K)&& \text{Set of mixture proportions for all $K$ contributors}\\
    &&&\text{such that }\textstyle\sum_{k=1}^K \pi_k =1 \\
    &\textit{$p_a$}&& \text{Population allele frequency of allele $a$}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

And the result:

[image]

So I want dots in between for instance a and allele, but also in between A_m and 'All alleles...', so that there are no dots in between the next line ('when individuals...')

Thanks in advance! And sorry if I missed things in my code, I do not do this very often :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a tabular. In the following, I have used `{tabularx}` from the eponymous package.

The dotted lines are inserted with the command `\dotfill`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{bm,bbm}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}  % for dummy text
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\bigskip
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{$}l<{$\enspace\dotfill}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
    a & Allele\\
    m \in \{1,..., M\}& Marker\\
    k \in \{1,..., K\}& Contributor\\
    g_{m,k} = (g_{m,k,1},g_{m,k,2})& Genotype of contributor $k$ at marker $m$, consisting of two alleles\\
    \textbf{g}_{m} = (g_{m,1},...,g_{m,K})& Set of genotypes for all $K$ contributors \\
    \textbf{A}_m & All alleles at marker $m$ observed in database plus new alleles discovered
    when individuals are added\\
    \textbf{Y}_m & Observed peak heights of the alleles in $\textbf{A}_m$\\
     Y_{m,a} & Observed peak height of allele $a$ at marker $m$\\
     Y_{m,a,k} & Peak height contribution of contributor $k$ to~$Y_{m,a}$\\
     \mathbb{Q}_m = \{(a,b): a,b\in \textbf{A}_m\} & The set of all possible genotypes at marker $m$\\
    \pi_k & Mixture proportion: proportion of total DNA added by contributor $k$\\
    \bm{\pi} = (\pi_1, ..., \pi_K)& Set of mixture proportions for all $K$ contributors
    such that $\sum_{k=1}^K \pi_k =1$ \\
    p_a & Population allele frequency of allele $a$
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

If you want the dots of the different lines perfectly aligned, replace `\dotfill` by `\leaders\hbox to 1mm{\hss.\hss}\hfill`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{bm,bbm}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}  % for dummy text
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\bigskip
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{$}l<{\enspace$\leaders\hbox to 1mm{\hss.\hss}\hfill}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
    a & Allele\\
    m \in \{1,..., M\}& Marker\\
    k \in \{1,..., K\}& Contributor\\
    g_{m,k} = (g_{m,k,1},g_{m,k,2})& Genotype of contributor $k$ at marker $m$, consisting of two alleles\\
    \textbf{g}_{m} = (g_{m,1},...,g_{m,K})& Set of genotypes for all $K$ contributors \\
    \textbf{A}_m & All alleles at marker $m$ observed in database plus new alleles discovered
    when individuals are added\\
    \textbf{Y}_m & Observed peak heights of the alleles in $\textbf{A}_m$\\
     Y_{m,a} & Observed peak height of allele $a$ at marker $m$\\
     Y_{m,a,k} & Peak height contribution of contributor $k$ to~$Y_{m,a}$\\
     \mathbb{Q}_m = \{(a,b): a,b\in \textbf{A}_m\} & The set of all possible genotypes at marker $m$\\
    \pi_k & Mixture proportion: proportion of total DNA added by contributor $k$\\
    \bm{\pi} = (\pi_1, ..., \pi_K)& Set of mixture proportions for all $K$ contributors
    such that $\sum_{k=1}^K \pi_k =1$ \\
    p_a & Population allele frequency of allele $a$
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]

Comment: Thanks! I got it kind of working: latex has trouble with the $ in the tabularx definition, what is this for? It thinks it is working in math mode. And is there a way to let the dots continue a little longer? Now there is some space left between the last dot and the definition.

Comment: I have changed  a little my (second) proposition.

Answer (score 2):

`align` is definitely not the right tool for this.

I propose a different approach than with a tabular, allowing page breaks.

Each entry is input with the `\entry` command taking two arguments; the first is typeset in math mode, in a box `\symbolswd` wide; the second one is typeset in a hanging paragraph, with dot leaders filling the space.

The `\symbolswd` length is computed for each entry and the final value is saved in the `.aux` file so at the next run the width will be the same for all entries (with warning if the widths differ).

The warning is issued when the value of `\symbolswd` at the end of the environment is different from the value at the beginning. In this case a rerun will solve the issue.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{bm,bbm}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\symbolswd}
\newenvironment{symbols}
 {%
  \chapter*{Symbols}
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
  \edef\current@symbolswd{\the\symbolswd}%
  \sloppy
  \interlinepenalty=10000 % no page break in a two line entry
 }
 {%
  \ifdim\current@symbolswd=\symbolswd
  \else
    \@latex@warning@no@line{Rerun to get list of symbols right}%
  \fi
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\global\symbolswd=\the\symbolswd}%
 }
\newcommand{\entry}[2]{%
  \par\addvspace{\smallskipamount}
  \sbox\z@{$#1$\qquad}%
  \ifdim\wd\z@<\symbolswd \setlength{\symbolswd}{\wd\z@}\fi
  \hangindent=\symbolswd
  \makebox[\symbolswd][s]{$#1$\leaders\hbox to 4pt{\hss.\hss}\hfill}%
  #2\par
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{symbols}
\entry{a}{Allele}

\entry{m \in \{1,\dots, M\}}{Marker}

\entry{k \in \{1,\dots, K\}}{Contributor}

\entry{g_{m,k} = (g_{m,k,1},g_{m,k,2})}{Genotype of contributor $k$ 
  at marker $m$, consisting of two alleles}

\entry{g_{m} = (g_{m,1},\dots,g_{m,K})}{Set of genotypes for all $K$ contributors}

\entry{\mathbf{A}_m}{All alleles at marker $m$ observed in database
  plus new alleles discovered when individuals are added}

\entry{\mathbf{Y}_m}{Observed peak heights of the alleles in $\mathbf{A}_m$}

\entry{Y_{m,a}}{Observed peak height of allele $a$ at marker $m$}

\entry{Y_{m,a,k}}{Peak height contribution of contributor $k$ to $Y_{m,a}$}

\entry{\mathbb{Q}_m = \{(a,b): a,b\in \mathbf{A}_m\}}{The set of all possible 
  genotypes at marker $m$}

\entry{\pi_k}{Mixture proportion: proportion of total DNA added by contributor $k$}

\entry{\bm{\pi} = (\pi_1,\dots,\pi_K)}{Set of mixture proportions for all $K$ contributors
  such that $\sum_{k=1}^K \pi_k =1$}

\entry{p_a}{Population allele frequency of allele $a$}
\end{symbols}

\end{document}
```

[image]